# Web API 2: POST or PUT for accepting an entity

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, put, http-verbs

I.e. we have a system with entities (requests) from one type of users. There are another type of users, which can accept or decline these entities. What should I use (PUT or POST) to accept/decline concrete request for concrete user? As I understand, POST should create a new resource, but we don't create any new resource. PUT should update a resource, but in our case we don't update a resource, we make some actions about resource for concrete user.
What should be better to use, PUT or POST in this case?

Comment: There is no absolute in terms of verbs usage, but the most common case I've come across for HTTP verbs for custom actions is to use POST on a named sub-resource (i.e. POST /users/{some-identifier}/accept, POST /users/{some-identifier}/decline).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PUT vs POST in REST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)

Comment: it kinda sounds like you're updating the state of an entity (something like submitted -> accepted/declined), so perhaps a PUT is actually what you're looking for